# $inc of mongoose to prevent negative value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My below code work just fine deducting credit (it work for increment which is great) from user using $inc in mongoose, but the value **can become negative which is what I don't want**, any option to prevent that?

```
module.exports.deduct_credit = function(subscriber_email,callback){
  Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {email: subscriber_email},
    {$inc:{credit:price_per_use}},
    {new: true})
    .exec(callback);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `but the value can become negative`? at which place you want to restrict?

Comment: @abdulbarik if my current value is 0 and my price_per_use is -10, it would be -10. Credit should not be -10, the min value is 0. How to restrict that to happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the `$inc` behaviour but you can  do a checkpoint to stop it after `zero`

```
module.exports.deduct_credit = function(subscriber_email, callback) {
  Users.findOneAndUpdate({
      email: subscriber_email,
      credit:{$gte: 0}
    }, {
      $inc: {
        credit: price_per_use
      }
    }, {
      new: true
    })
    .exec(callback);
}
```

Now it will update if the `credit` value is greater that `zero`

Hope this can work for you

Comment: why not `$gte` ? says the user has 10, and he used 10, it's still ok to give him to power to add fom 0. right?

Comment: Yes you can use just give you a way to handle your issue, you can use it in your requirement way

Comment: so it is not $gt but $gte?

Comment: both are right. it just `less than` or `less than or equal to`

Comment: $gt is wrong. if user have 10 credit, he used 10, the next increment won't happens because the credit is 0, it won't work coz credit is not greater than 0.

Comment: I tested both `$gt` and `$gte`. If `$gte`, when the counter is 0 on DB, then it discounts once more (negative value recorded as result), after that, no more. If you want to prevent the value to be negative, then right answer is `$gt`  because it can not consider zero any longer so that we can ignore 0.